# High pitch sound noise from Notebook

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, asus-laptop, noise

I've just bought an ASUS N752VX notebook, with Windows 10. (with SSD inside, not HDD)

What I noticed is that there's a high-pitched noise coming out, very faint normally (even in stand-by), but somewhat audible in several scenarios, especially when using Wireless SteelSeries Sensei mouse. (Using a lower polling frequency on the mouse, also alters the noise rate, but not its intensity).

It gets the loudest when I have my charger plugged-in, I open a website in any browser, and I move the mouse.

The noise originates near the left side, near the area of the charging input.

I tried switching USB ports. Tried disabling and reinstalling drivers for audio, video, chipset, and thermal mgmt. I also swapped chargers. Did clean install. Sound card volume has no impact.

When unplugging the power, the noise is barely audible, but still present. When also removing the Sensei docking base from USB, it's as gone, but in complete silence it may be heard very faintly.

Prior to this laptop, I had an N751 that I also used with the same SSD and same Sensei mouse, and it never had this issue.

Is this normal for this notebook, or should I be worried about some component (maybe power related?) being flawed? What further tests could I take, in order to identify to source, and a possible remedy?

It's covered by warranty, but I'd hate to have it sent into service for two weeks, just to get it back poked around and without a fix.

Comment: It sounds like coil whine.  If that's what it is, it's harmless, just annoying it you notice it.  That probably won't be something they will "repair" under warranty because it doesn't affect anything (other than you, but you're not included in the warranty).  If you can identify the culprit, you can probably eliminate the noise, but I wouldn't do that while it's still under warranty.

Comment: Is there any way for me to confirm it's coil whine - without tearing the notebook apart? Even if not, since this is brand new, I can have it returned within 14days for whatever reason, but before doing so I'd like to know if this is something general with the N752VX series, or just this one, because there's no point in having it replaced just to get another one with the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to access the components to confirm what's making the noise.  Coil whine is a basic problem with anything that contains coils, they act like little speakers.  The manufacturers usually put some material on them to basically glue it together, which is the solution.  It could be that they missed one on your unit.  You could encounter this on any unit, so there's no guarantee that a replacement would be better.  But if you get unlimited, repeat 14 day returns/replacements, there wouldn't be much to lose.